# How to get the primary key values after insert select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to create a SQL script with many step in it.

First of all, I need to insert data into a  Parent Table.

How can I Get the list of primary key value

Here is an example of what I'm trying to perform.

MyParentTable
MyParentID PK
col1,
col2,
col3

--INSERT VALUE INTO THE PARENT TABLE

```
insert into MyParentTable(col1,col2,col3)
select SDATA1,SDATA2,SDATA3
from ExampleTables
```

I Would like to get the list of my newly entries.

How to do that?

IMPORTANT NOTE : Consider that MyParentTable can alreaydy contains data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into dbo.MyParentTable(col1,col2,col3)
output inserted.identity_column_name
select SDATA1,SDATA2,SDATA3
from dbo.ExampleTables;
```

If there are foreign keys involved, you may have to use a @table variable for temporary holding.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT);

insert into dbo.MyParentTable(col1,col2,col3)
output inserted.identity_column_name INTO @t
select SDATA1,SDATA2,SDATA3
from dbo.ExampleTables;

SELECT id FROM @t;
```